# how to change wordpress content url using Velvet Blues Update URLs

Tags: wordpress

how to change wordpress content url using Velvet Blues Update URLs.when i am going to update url what is the old url and new url. i am not identifying so please help and tell me what is the old and new url for my Velvet Blues Update URLs.

Comment: Your old URL's are the original URL's. 
Velvet Blues Update URLs will update those to the address of your new site

Comment: but my old domain and new domain is same

Comment: If your old domain and new domain are the same, what is the need to update the URLs?

Comment: yes but the post content is not showing in post.-@NeilKennedy

Comment: Are you suggesting you have moved the `wp-content` directory rather than the site as a whole?

Comment: yes i moved all files of public_html folder @NathanDawson

Comment: What is working?
What is NOT working?